# Where M is a matrix calculate a formula for M^n

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $$M = \begin{bmatrix} -7 & 8 \\ -8 & -7 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer.  (Your formulas should not contain complex numbers.)  Your answer should be in the form of a matrix.

I diagonalized to the form $M = P D P^{-1}$  and $M^n = P D^n P^{-1}$ where $P$ is my matrix of eigenvectors and $D$ is my matrix of eigenvalues.

My final answer after diagonalization was
$$M^n = \begin{bmatrix} .5((-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) & (i/2)(-(-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) \\ (.5/i)(-(-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) & .5((-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) \end{bmatrix}$$

I can't seem to find an answer not in terms of complex numbers.  Can someone show me what I'm missing?

Comment: Note that all your complex numbers come in the form $$(a+bi)^n + (a-bi)^n$$ It's a nice quick exercise to prove from the binomial formula that these numbers are always real. I didn't check your answer directly, but if it's correct (and you can check yourself by substituting a few values for $n$) it's legitimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Write your eigenvalues in polar form $re^{i\theta}$ instead of $x + iy$. (so the two eigenvalues are $re^{i\theta}, re^{-i\theta}$). Recall polar coordinates are given by $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $\tan(\theta) = y/x$ (so $\theta = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$ if $x>0$ and $\tan^{-1}(y/x) + \pi$ if $x<0$).

Then, when you compute $D^n$, use De Moivre's formula:

$$
\left(re^{i\theta}\right)^n = r^n(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))^n = r^n (\cos(n\theta) + i \sin(n\theta)) \\
\left(re^{-i\theta}\right)^n = r^n(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(-\theta))^n = r^n (\cos(n\theta) + i \sin(-n\theta)) = r^n (\cos(n\theta) - i \sin(n\theta))
$$

by using even and odd properties of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

In particular, if you have to add these two values, you'll get
$$
\left(re^{i\theta}\right)^n + \left(re^{-i\theta}\right)^n = 2r^n\cos(n\theta)
$$

Comment: So -7=x and 8=y right? but what is r and theta equal to?

Comment: Small addendum:  the off-diagonal entries have $i$ as a coefficient (remember that $1/i = -i$) and correspondingly, the expressions are a *difference* of $n$th powers of conjugates which are purely imaginary quantities.  Hint:  they involve the $\sin$ function.

Comment: @MathematicalAnomaly $r$ and $\theta$ are the usual polar coordinates. I edited in some discussion.

Answer (score 3):

$$  M = (M + 7 I) + (-7)I $$
and the two pieces commute, so you can use the binomial theorem.  So $M = 8J - 7 I,$ where
$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
What are $J^2, J^3, J^4?$

Having fiddled with it later, I do not see any genuine "closed form" solution except the one you already had, with the complex numbers. So, the entires are certain sums of integers involving binomial coefficients.

Comment: That's just how I was about to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Write $$M={1\over\sqrt{113}}\pmatrix{\cos x&\sin x\cr-\sin x&\cos x\cr}$$ where $\tan x=-8/7$ (so $x=-\arctan(8/7)$). Prove by induction that $$\pmatrix{\cos x&\sin x\cr-\sin x&\cos x\cr}^n=\pmatrix{\cos nx&\sin nx\cr-\sin nx&\cos nx\cr}$$ and deduce that $$M^n=113^{n/2}\pmatrix{\cos nx&\sin nx\cr-\sin nx&\cos nx\cr}$$

Comment: And hence $\cos(nx) = T_n(7/\sqrt{113})$ and $\sin(nx) = - \dfrac{8}{\sqrt{113} n} T_n'(7/\sqrt{113})$ where $T_n$ is the $n$'th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.