# Find $M^n$ of a matrix $M$ whenever diagonalization is possible

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> Let $$M = \begin{bmatrix} -7 & 8 \\ -8 & -7 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Find
>   formulas for the entries of $M^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. 
>   (Your formulas should not contain complex numbers.)  Your answer
>   should be in the form of a matrix.

I diagonalized to the form $M = P D P^{-1}$  and $M^n = P D^n P^{-1}$
 where $P$ is my matrix of eigenvectors and $D$ is my matrix of
 eigenvalues.

> My final answer after diagonalization was $$M^n = \begin{bmatrix}
> > .5((-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) & (i/2)(-(-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) \\
>  >(.5/i)(-(-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) & .5((-7+8i)^n+(-7-8i)^n) \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> I had a hard time finding an answer not in terms of complex numbers. Can someone show me what I'm missing?

I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568628/where-m-is-a-matrix-calculate-a-formula-for-mn) a couple of days ago and I finally had time to correct it. Can someone check my solution, Every value I can think of works for it but it was an online homework assignment and my solution isn't being accepted.

After using De Moivre's formula as BaronVT suggested I came up with the solution

$$M^n = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{113^n}\cdot\cos\left(n\cdot\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{-7}\right)+\pi\right)\right) & \sqrt{113^n}\cdot\sin\left(n\cdot\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{-7}\right)+\pi\right)\right) \\ -\sqrt{113^n}\cdot\sin\left(n\cdot\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{-7}\right)+\pi\right)\right) & \sqrt{113^n}\cdot\cos\left(n\cdot\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{-7}\right)+\pi\right)\right) \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I have posted an answer over at the earlier version of the question. It comes to pretty much what you have, only without the $+\pi$, and without using de Moivre or anything involving complex numbers.